# Should I use SSL if my parameters are already encrypted?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I use GET to send parameters to a server. The parameters are encrypted and Base16 encoded.

Is it still important to use SSL?

**EDIT:**
Would using SSL prevent attacks like calling the server URL successively too many times until it stops responding or the server goes down?

Comment: I'd not just use SSL, but also move parameter passing to POST in order for parameters not to be stored in server logs (at least by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL should be used if you need any of the following

1. data should be encrypted, so that only the recipient is able to read them
2. data should be safe against tampering, e.g. nor only should an attacker not be able to read them, he should also not be able to change them
3. you want to make sure that the recipient is the right server, e.g. verify its identity

I think just encrypting the GET data does not help against 3. It might help against 2 if you've also added a cryptographic checksum.

Comment: oh, point 3 is really important! I am using a server to activate my software, my app will call the server, but, aren't hackers able to patch my app any way? so that it skips my app license validation?

Comment: As long as you cannot deny an attacker to run a modified version of your program he can disable any checks. So if your program should run on an open platform like the PC you can only make it hard enough to debug for most attackers or you get your money with in-app purchases, advertisement or similar stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, generally you should use SSL because;

1. SSL adds negligible CPU overhead in modern computers.
2. SSL doesn't just encrypt the content, it also prevents Man in the Middle attacks because it verifies the identity of the server.
3. If you don't encrypt the entire communication with something like SSL, an attacker/interloper can gain valuable knowledge about your protocol and systems.

Answer (score 0):

If they are encrypted server side it wouldn't need ssl.   But in this case why though would it need to be passed to the client side?   Truly encrypted data wouldn't be usable.

Comment: My variables are encrypted local side, and de-encrypted at server, then the response will contain encrypted variables that will be decrypted again local side .. I don't use a browser, its an application ..

Comment: The only issue is if this encrypting in a web browser.  Can another person see the encryption process?   If so, they can possibly decrypt it.  I think the only time this is safe is if you are using shared secrets across two private servers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SSL *instead of* your own encryption scheme. SSL not only encrypts but authenticates and protects you against man-in-the-middle, replay, and truncation attacks, which I'm prepared to bet you haven't even thought of in your own scheme.